# How to make link of the database in PHP

Tags: php, database, url, hyperlink

Hi I want to show URL as a link in PHP the URL is shown by query from database but it is not a link so I want to make it link like using  `<a href=""></a>` but I don't know what I am doing wrong

**My data show like this in browser**

```
ID  Name    URL

2   This    localhost/p_uploads/00.jpg
3   Nissan  localhost/p_uploads/7a.jpg
```

I want these URL's to be link so anyone can click on the url to open the image

**Here is my PHP Code:**

```
 <?php
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['loggedin'])){
        header("location:index.php");
    }

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){

header("location: index.php");
}
else {

?>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","user");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from private_uploads where username = '".$_SESSION['user']."'")
    or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>URL</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>",'<a href=' . $row['Link'] . '></a>',"</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";


//Views Counter


mysqli_close($con);}

?> 


<?php
  $url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  echo "<a href='$url'>back</a>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
 echo "<td>",'<a href=' . $row['Link'] . '></a>',"</td>";
```

for this

```
 echo '<td><a href="' . $row['Link'] . '">[a name here would be nice]</a></td>';
```

you are missing the **""** in the generated **href**

Answer (score 0):

You're producing links that look like this:

```
<a href="localhost/p_uploads/00.jpg"></a>
```

That's both an invalid URL (unless you really do have a `localhost/p_uplaods` folder) and a link with no body, so you'll never see it.

If you want to access `localhost` the **host**, and not the folder, you should use use an absolute path on the current host, `/p_uploads/00.jpg`, or a fully qualified URL: `http://localhost/p_uploads/00.jpg`.

Comment: Yeah I can do this but I am asking for turning it to link if you understand what I mean @meagar

Answer (score 0):

Your link looks like this:

```
<a href="localhost/p_uploads/00.jpg"></a>
```

It doesn't have a HTTP protocol. The link should look like this:

```
<a href="http://localhost/p_uploads/00.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a problem on this line:

`echo "<td>",'<a href=' . $row['Link'] . '></a>',"</td>";`

As you are referring to `Link` whereas in your database the column is called `URL`. Also add a text to the  tag:

`echo '<td><a href="http://' . $row['URL'] . '">View</a></td>';`

Comment: Nope bro there is no mistake in it I have run this script and it's working fine in my database there is no column link URL it is Link @Bagonyi