# Output link from mySQL database into table

Tags: php, html

below is my PHP code, I just can't figure out how to make the "INFO" text appear as a clickable url. I've seen the echo method but not one that works for the below. This method needs to create a link using the data and also set the link as the text used inside the table.

```
  <?php
        if(isset($data) && !empty($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $row) {

                @$count += 1;
                $keyword = htmlspecialchars($row['Keyword']);
                $suburb = htmlspecialchars($row['Suburb']);
                $postcode = htmlspecialchars($row['Postcode']);
                $status = htmlspecialchars($row['Status']);
                $info = htmlspecialchars($row['Info']);

                @$table_row .= "<tr><td>$count</td><td>$keyword</td><td>$suburb</td><td>$postcode</td><td>$status</td><td>$info</td></tr>";
            }
            echo @$table_row;
        }
        ?>
```

It's the **'Info'** column that i want to pull in as a url.

Cheers,
Curtis
http://www.homegiraffe.com.au

Comment: Maybe `$info = '<a href="location?">' . htmlspecialchars($row['Info']) . '</a>';`? You also don't need `!empty` and `isset` just have the `!empty`.

Comment: What does the error log say? Did you script crash before?

Comment: AWESOME that fixed it. the first time i tried it failed but then i realised that i'd forgotten to copy the ; added that in and it worked. Legend thanks @chris

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make link of the database in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287687/how-to-make-link-of-the-database-in-php)

Comment: Yeah i just couldn't figure out how to edit it out as the code was different. The text appears as a link but it doesn't go through to the link saved in the Database. This is obviously because you've put "location?" in the href lookup. How would i replace this location text with the text in the "info" column from the DB?

Comment: `info` is a URL? Just concatenate it, if it is not a URL or is partial may get a bit trickier.

Comment: Yeah the text in the "info" box is a url. So this works: '$info = '<a href="' . $row['Info'] . '">[a name here would be nice]</a>';' but where it says "a name here would be nice" i'd just like it to display the url...

Comment: Combine my first comment and that answer. Also use `htmlspecialchars` or you could be open to XSS injections.

Comment: Yeah i tried that but it didn't seem to work. All good i'll find a work around. thanks for your help Chris!

Comment: Sorry i missed something in the code. Your right (as usual) it did work. Heres the code: ' $info = '<a href="' . $row['Info'] . '">' . htmlspecialchars($row['Info']) . '</a>'; '

Answer (score 1):

```
$info = '<a href="' . $row['Info'] . '">' . htmlspecialchars($row['Info']) . '</a>';
```

This is the answer. Thanks to Chris85 for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```html
<?php
        if(isset($data) && !empty($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $row) {

                @$count += 1;
                $keyword = htmlspecialchars($row['Keyword']);
                $suburb = htmlspecialchars($row['Suburb']);
                $postcode = htmlspecialchars($row['Postcode']);
                $status = htmlspecialchars($row['Status']);
                $info = htmlspecialchars($row['Info']);
?>
  <tr><td><?php echo $count;?></td><td><?php echo $keyword;?></td><td><?php echo $suburb;?></td><td><?php echo $postcode?></td><td><?php echo $status;?></td><td><a href="<?php echo $row['Info'];?>"><?php echo $info;?></a></td></tr>;
<?php
            }
        }
        ?>
```

and it work very good :)